# Weird behaviour of find() function (python2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

`find('asdf','')` finds an empty string in `'asdf'` hence it returns `0`. 
Similarly, `find('asdf','',3)` starts to search for the string at index position `3` and hence return `3`.
Since the last index is `3`, `find('asdf','',4)` should return `-1` but it returns `4` and starts to return `-1` only if the starting index is more than or equal to `(last_index)+2`. Why is this so?

Comment: You mean string.find(...)?

Comment: @MeNa No, I mean find('target','key'). In my case key is an empty string.

Comment: Why do you expect it to return `-1`?

Comment: @ThiefMaster Because it should start to check from index position 4 while my string just has upto index position 3.

Comment: The question that this question has been marked as a duplicate of has also been marked as a duplicate of another question which in my opinion is a wrong decision. That question asks about a totally different thing. First of all it asks about a method while mine is of a function. I don't know if their internal workings are the same just because they have the same name. Even the main point of that question is very different from mine if the details of that question are read properly. Now the duplicate doesn't have answers that I'm able to comprehend.